# Help me identify a cluster

Tags: exoplanet, globular-clusters, star-cluster

as I was browsing Nasa's Eyes few days ago, I saved a screenshot, [image: [img]https://i.imgur.com/w1rpBkr.jpg[/img]] but it seems text is blurrry, supher-485, first letter is S ends with er-485 from as I can read
it kinda looked like Cosmic Web, Indra's net, so i saved cool screenshot
Help me identify this cluster?

Comment: Not enough to go on. No coordinates or text are visible. The only thing I can think of is Slipher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this appears to be a screenshot of [Eyes on Exoplanets](https://eyes.nasa.gov/eyes-on-exoplanets.html), I searched for "exoplanet 485" and found [Kepler-485 b](http://exoplanet.eu/catalog/kepler-485_b/).
With the colors exaggerated, the label area could be "Kepler-485" in yellow overwritten with "Sun" in orange.
If this is correct, it's not a cluster, just a star with a planet, plus some artifacts from the instrument which took the image.

[image: detail of OP's screenshot]

Comment: Oh yes, you might be right, thank you. SInce I was zooming out of exoplanets, sun is also highlighted, it kinda looked like Cosmic Web, Indra's net, so i saved cool screenshot